# Is it possible to define a default wrapper for content in <router-outlet>?

Tags: html, angular, router-outlet

My `app.component.html` looks pretty clean at the moment:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

It renders something similar to this:

```
<body>
    <app-header>
        <header></header>
    </app-header>
    <router-outlet>
        [rendered content]
    </router-outlet>
    <app-footer>
        <footer></footer>
    </app-footer>
</body>
```

Now I want a `<main>`-element to be wrapped around all `[rendered content]`, like:

```
<router-outlet>
    <main>
        [rendered content]
    </main>
</router-outlet>
```

---

*Is this possible?*

---

At the moment I'm wrapping `<router-outlet>` in `<main>`. But it doesn't feel so clean:<sup>*</sup>

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

… as it renders to:

```
<main _ngcontent-c0="">
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
</main>
```

---

<sub>* I know this is very subjective.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not possible.

Any component that gets injected to the template using a router-outlet will get injected as a sibling of the  `< router-outlet >` and not as its child.

As a result, the following will never become true:

```
<router-outlet>
    <main>
        [rendered content]
    </main>
</router-outlet>
```

Please see how the routed component is a sibling as in the example below:

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, didn't notice that it is injected as a sibling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do router outlets by giving your router a name:

```
<router-outlet name="main">
</router-outlet>
```

So you have a router outlet for the vast page and a router for the inner part.
So you'll have a page that has

```
  <main>
    <router-outlet name="main">
    </router-outlet>
  </main>
```

and your app component is

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But honestly **I don't recommend this at all** because it makes the URLs messy 
ergo.

```
 /home/(main:somePage)
```

It makes the routing messy just not worth it.
Only wrote this because you asked if it is possible, not because I endorse this.